# How to change button's text on Click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my page, I have a "Read More" button and when someone presses that button it expands, so the user can read more information [(button not pressed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sglFc.png). This is how it looks like when the user has pressed the "Read More" button [(button pressed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBgBq.png). I've read many posts here on Stack Overflow and couldn't find a solution. So I want the text on the button to change to "Read Less" instead of staying "Read More" when the user clicks on it.

JS/CSS/HTML:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Read More</button>
<div class="panel">
  This appears when user presses "Read More"
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just manipulate `textContent` property of current element i.e. `this.textContent = "Read Less"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `onclick` handler you're currently checking the state of the "panel" and adjusting styling accordingly.  You can simultaneously adjust the `.innerText` of the clicked button.  Something like this:

```
if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    this.innerText = "Read More"; // here
} else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    this.innerText = "Read Less"; // and here
}
```

Comment: There's no need for an additional test. The code is already testing which of the two states are being toggled between by examining `maxHeight`.

Comment: @Quentin: Good catch, I didn't notice that conditional.  I'll update...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the button's text inside the `if -- else` block where you're changing the view of the `div` without having to create another test, and since the `if -- else` block is in the on click method of the button, you can use `this` to target the button:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      this.innerText = "Read More"; // 'this' is the button
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      this.innerText = "Read Less"; // 'this' is the button
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Read More</button>
<div class="panel">
  This appears when user presses "Read More"
</div>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well just change its `innerHTML` like this:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      this.innerHTML = "Read More";
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      this.innerHTML = "Read Less";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Read More</button>
<div class="panel">
  This appears when user presses "Read More"
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Toggle the **innerHTML** for your button.

```
if (panel.style.maxHeight) {

    this.innerHTML = "Read More";
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {

    this.innerHTML = "Read Less";
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
```

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
   if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
    
    this.innerHTML = "Read More";
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
    
    this.innerHTML = "Read Less";
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Read More</button>
<div class="panel">
  This appears when user presses "Read More"
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by below code

```
if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      this.innerText = "Read More"; // 'this' is the button
} else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      this.innerText = "Read Less"; // 'this' is the button
}
```